# hardhat-shorthand is not working

Tags: solidity, hardhat, npm

I installed `hardhat-shorthand` using the [yarn package manager](https://yarnpkg.com/). However, running `hh <code>` throws the following error:

```shell
hh: command not found hardhat
```

I'm using the following code for installing the package:

```shell
yarn global add hardhat-shorthand
```

I'm referring the following doc: [Link](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/command-line-completion)

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:
Instead of `yarn`, use `npm` or `npx` for installing.

Use `npm install --global hardhat-shorthand`

Instead of `yarn global add hardhat-shorthand`

Hardhat team mentions something similar in their [Context](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/command-line-completion#context) paragraph (refer below):

*Out of best practice, Hardhat projects use a local installation of the npm package hardhat to make sure everyone working on the project is using the same version. This is why you need to use npx or npm scripts to run Hardhat.
This approach has the downside of there being no way to provide autocomplete suggestions directly for the hardhat command, as well as making the CLI commands longer. These are the two issues that hh solves.*

Answer (score 3):

`yarn` won't complain if it can't install some components as a result of a lack of administrator privileges. Try doing the installation as root and it should work.

```sh
sudo yarn global add hardhat-shorthand
```

Comment: yep this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

you can add yarn bin in PATH:

```
yarn global dir # get yarn bin path
```